# Filter object of array by array length

Tags: javascript, object, filter

I am trying to sort object of arrays by arrays length, for example, i try to get from this object array where length more than 3

```
 {
  friend: [
    { id: 0, name: 'A' },
    { id: 1, name: 'V' },
    { id: 2, name: 'C' },
    { id: 3, name: 'D' }
  ],
  people: [ { id: 0, name: 'A' }, { id: 1, name: 'B' } ]  
}
```

and the result will array friend. I try to do this

```
function getPart (obj) {
    for (let key in obj) { 
        if (obj[key].length>=4) {
            console.log(obj[key]);
        }
}}
```

but I want to try to do it with `filter` object but I have no idea how to make it

Comment: I'm not entirely sure of what you are trying to do. Could you elaborate what the output should look like? Welcome to SO by the way!

Comment: I want to use filter instead if

Comment: Ok. I got confused by the title. No sorting is required? You simply want to find the `friend` object?

Answer (score 2):

We can achieve that using `Object.entries()` and `reduce()` function.

Here's an example:

**JS**

```js
 let data = {
  friend: [
    { id: 0, name: 'A' },
    { id: 1, name: 'V' },
    { id: 2, name: 'C' },
    { id: 3, name: 'D' }
  ],
  people: [ { id: 0, name: 'A' }, { id: 1, name: 'B' } ]  
}

// Convert first the object to an array using Object.entries so we can loop it using reduce() function
// Then we make a condition statement if the object's length is >= 4, then we'll filter that to the new object.
let new_data = Object.entries(data).reduce((a, b) => a = {...a, ...(b[1].length >= 4 ? {[b[0]]: b[1]} : {})} ,{})
console.log(new_data) // Expected result: { friend: [Object] }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just one line:

> Object.values(obj).filter(ob => ob.length >= 4);

```js
const ob = {
  friend: [
    { id: 0, name: 'A' },
    { id: 1, name: 'V' },
    { id: 2, name: 'C' },
    { id: 3, name: 'D' }
  ],
  people: [ { id: 0, name: 'A' }, { id: 1, name: 'B' } ]  
}



function getPart (obj) {
    const filtered = Object.values(obj).filter(ob => ob.length >= 4);
    console.log(filtered);
}


getPart(ob);
```